# SQL Server backup jobs and Agent jobs

Tags: sql-server, database-backups, sql-agent-job

I am creating a backup schedule for a database which also has SQL agent jobs running and I have noticed that the transaction log backup I am thinking of scheduling will run at the same time as one of SQL agent jobs.

Does anyone know whether this would cause an issue having a backup job and a Agent job running at the same time? Or will it cause the SQL agent job to run slowly?

Comment: You can safely `backup log` on any schedule you choose, and we have no idea what this "other" agent job is.

Comment: The agent job is a job which does checks and then depending on the results sends emails. So if this job and a backup job runs at the same time will it cause an issue?

Comment: No backing up a transaction log should not interfere with any other operations. Factor in how much your log grows is used between scheduled backups and always test any changes before you deploy to production.

Comment: You should also confirm that your database is actually set to a recovery model that requires transaction log backups to occur (eg. if the recovery model on the database is "Simple", there is no need for transaction log backups to occur).

Comment: it is set to Full recovery model